# How to avoid repeated instantiation and garbage collection for a trivial class?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, performance, optimization, game-development

I am developing a 2D tile-based RPG game for desktop and (hopefully) Android. To represent a tile location in the game, I am using a class called `Location`, which has a value for `x`, `y`, and `room`. `room` refers to the `Room` that the `Location` is in. I use the `Location` class for calculations like whether a tile is passable or impassable, the tile that a character is facing, etc. Originally, I used `x`, `y`, and `room` values for the character, game objects, etc. classes, but decided to replace them with instances of `Location` instead.

From [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888255/using-pool-class-in-libgdx), and elsewhere, I am under the impression that instantiating these `Location` objects over and over would be less than ideal for performance, especially on Android platforms. But it also seems like pooling (see the links) `Location`s is too much work to implement. For example, I can get a new `Location` from a `Location` and a `Direction` (an enum) by calling `Location.add(Direction)` which I would use in character movement calculations (depending on what `Direction` the player is directing). It would be extremely inconvenient to have to manually call "free" on an object that I intend to use only in one line, for example in pseudocode `character.setLocation(character.getLocation().add(character.facingDirection))` versus

```
var tempLocation = character.getLocation().add(character.facingDirection) // assuming for convenience that the add method uses a global pool of Location s
character.setLocation(tempLocation)
tempLocation.free() // assuming this frees it from the global pool
```

The idea of using a `Location` class instead of `x`, `y`, and `room` values in every relevant object is to *simplify* the process of coding, not make it more complex. (And, of course, it seems to me the "correct" object-oriented way). Are there any other viable ways to maintain decent performance without avoiding the `Location` class altogether? Or, for that matter, is performance even a concern in this case?

For completion's sake, I'm using Java, Scala, and LibGDX.

Comment: How is `tempLocation.free()` any more work than `tempLocation = null`?  If a character already has a location, why do you need to instantiate a new object?  Why not just store the location object as a member of the character object for later use?

Comment: Also, you haven't mentioned anything about profiling the application to find out if this is a real problem or just an imagined one.  You say that you're interested in the "correct" object-oriented way, but some of your practices seem a bit... unorthodox.

Comment: @RobertHarvey in this situation, I wouldn't be using `tempLocation` at all, it would remain anonymous/implict (since it's only used in `setLocation`). And I suppose in this example, we could make `add` a mutator, but some other calculations involving game objects would use a method that returns a boolean such as `GameObject.contains(character.getLocation().add(character.facingDirection))`, where the `Location` used is used immediately and then discarded.

Comment: @RobertHarvey could you elaborate what you mean by unorthodox? I haven't had a ton of experience with software design

Comment: Are you trying to keep a history of locations?  I don't understand why you don't just store the location in the character.  The manner in which you store it (i.e. a data class) is not that important.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the character can interact with other objects in the game without moving to their space; when the player presses a certain key the game searches through each game object testing if they `contain` the location of the square the character is immediately facing

Comment: I still haven't heard anything yet that prevents you from simply storing that state in the character and providing a getter.  -1 for marking bad advice as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instantiating and collecting small, short-lived, temporary objects, is perfectly fine. It is what modern garbage collectors are good at.

Modern (generational) garbage collectors are built on a couple of assumptions: most objects die young, most objects are small, most objects don't escape, most objects are immutable, older objects don't contain references to younger objects. Only objects which *violate* these assumptions are expensive, and your objects *fulfill* these assumptions. Allocating an object in the young generation is just bumping a pointer (just like stack allocation in C, and cheaper than `malloc`) and collecting the young generation is O(#survivors), so if most objects are dead, collection is cheap also.

Re-using and pooling objects OTOH violates them: it artificially lengthens the lifetime of objects, the pool itself is large, references become non-local, objects are needlessly mutable (and needlessly mutated). *Unless* you have *specific* evidence to the contrary, object re-use and pooling is going to *hurt* GC, not help it.

---

You may note that the assumptions are trivially true for functional programming. Indeed, even though most modern garbage collectors are developed for imperative OO platforms (e.g. Sun's G1 for HotSpot, IBM's Metronome for J9, the .NET GC, Mono's scgen, Immix, Azul's Pauseless Collector, etc.), they end up being pretty good at FP. For example, Azul has demonstrated running the famous Clojure Ant Simulation Example on an 864 core machine with 768 GiByte of RAM with 700 parallel threads generating 20 GiByte/s of garbage, and the GC never induced noticeable pauses and never needed more than 20-30 cores (or in other words never more than ~30% of the available CPUs).

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection can become a performance issue in games, and might require special approaches. However, before you are *sure* that garbage collection of temporary `Location` instances is problematic, you would waste your time by trying to limit the amount of instances: “Premature optimization is the root of all evil.”

To decide whether you should go down this route, you first have to know whether your application even is “too slow”. Are you aiming for a specific framerate on your reference hardware? Do you want to limit memory consumption to under 1GB? Whatever your target is, explicitly define it, then measure it. To find the source of slowness, we can use profiler tools to guide us to those areas of code that use the most time. Focussing on these will have the greatest effect.

In any case, a class pool is unlikely to have a beneficial effect on performance for a simple `Location` class. I'm assuming a definition equivalent to this Java:

```
final class Location /* no interfaces, no parent classes */ {
  private final int x;
  private final int y;
  ... // methods and constructors
}
```

Such a class is very easily optimizable. If such a `Location` is used as a local variable (as in your example) in JIT-compiled code, there's a good chance that the object won't ever be explicitly garbage collected because it can be cheaply allocated on the stack, and the object's fields can be inlined. In theory, this can be just as efficient as having two plain `int location_x, location_y` variables and only using static methods on them.

In any case, my intuition indicates that maintaining a correct cache will likely be far more expensive than garbage collecting discarded objects, especially if the cache has to be synchronized between multiple threads. Of course, my intuition might be wrong and only hard data can tell us for sure – and the only way to find out is to run a benchmark before/after such a change.

Your proposed solution requiring a manual `free()` call is quite problematic, since this re-introduces the possibility of memory leaks. Experience with C and C++ shows that memory leaks are extremely easy to create if uncareful. In the code

```
Location l = ...;
something();
l.free();
```

if `something()` throws, the location will never be freed – a memory leak. This could be worked around with a `try … finally` block, or by a try-with-resource, but that is rather cumbersome for temporary values. Modern C++ helps programmers to limit these problems by making a distinction between owned and borrowed objects, and by automatic, deterministic destructors that are executed even when an exception is thrown. Java does not have any of these features because as a garbage collected language, it has less use for them.

If it turns out that you do actually need to avoid allocating too many Locations, you can just make them mutable. Your `Location#add()` seems to create a *new* Location – but if you update the existing Location instead, you can avoid that. A properly implemented `clone()` method lets you copy a location if a separate instance is needed. This is consistent with the way most Java objects already work, though it is admittedly a bit ugly in Scala.
While there is a potential source of bugs in forgetting to always `clone()` where necessary, this is way easier to get right than remembering to assure everything is `free()`d correctly.

Comment: -1 for the first paragraph, cavalierly tossing around the "premature optimization" quote without citing the *entire* quote and without explaining it properly.

Comment: -1 for paragraph 4.  Whether a class is allocated on the stack or the heap is an implementation detail in Java.  You can't rely on such mechanics.

Comment: -1 for paragraphs 6 and 7.  `free()` doesn't mean what you think it means here.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph actually offering something useful, albeit in a clumsy way.

Comment: Overall: -2. ..